# different websocket connections but received messages get mixed up

Tags: python, websocket

```
 import alice_blue
 from alice_blue import *
 
 
 
 class socket:
 
     #global variables
     live_data=[]
     socket_opened = False
     
     #credentials
     username=
     password=
     api_secret=
     app_id=
     twoFA=
     
     #access token and alice objects
     access_token = AliceBlue.login_and_get_access_token(username=username, password=password, twoFA=twoFA,  api_secret=api_secret, app_id=app_id)
 
     alice = AliceBlue(username=username, password=password, access_token=access_token, master_contracts_to_download=['NSE', 'BSE'])
     
 
 
     #alice.start_websocket handlers
     def _event_handler_quote_update(self,message):
         self.live_data.append(message)
 
     def _open_callback(self):
         self.socket_opened = True
 
 
     #init.py
     def __init__(self):
 
         self.alice.start_websocket(subscribe_callback=self._event_handler_quote_update,
                             socket_open_callback=self._open_callback,
                             run_in_background=True)
         
         while (self.socket_opened==False):
             pass

        #subscription methods
     def subscribe_nse_market(self,instruments):
              for x in instruments :
                           self.alice.subscribe(self.alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', x), LiveFeedType.MARKET_DATA)
     def subscribe_nse_snapquote(self,instruments):
              for x in instruments :
                           self.alice.subscribe(self.alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', x), LiveFeedType.SNAPQUOTE)
   
 
  
             
 a=alice_obj.socket()
 b=alice_obj.socket()
  

 ins=[ ]
 
 a.subscribe_nse_market(ins)
 b.subscribe_nse_snapquote(ins)
 
 #but both of the below gives same content with messges mixed up
 a.live_data
 b.live_data
```

#how can i make different socket connections to store messages separately in their respective objects.

I tried making live_data & event handler methods protected/private members. But still the same.

I guess the messages are directly streamed through a single channel in the device.

#thanksAlready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplification of your problem.

```py
class Foo:
    arr = []

    def add(self, value):
        self.arr.append(value)

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.add(1)
print(b.arr) # prints [1]
print(a.arr) # prints [1]

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = []

    def add(self, value):
        self.arr.append(value)

a = Bar()
b = Bar()
a.add(1)
print(b.arr) # prints []
print(a.arr) # prints [1]
```

In class `Foo`, arr is a class attribute which means it is shared among instances.
In class `Bar`, arr is an instance attribute.